# React: ReviewDetails.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'url')

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I'm trying to display the image per ID from my Strapi backend but when I run it in my frontend (ReactJS), it displays this error in my console:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";

export default function ReviewDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { loading, error, data } = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/reviews/' + id + '/?populate=*')
  const image = useFetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/upload/files/` + id);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  console.log(image);
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="review-card">
      <div className="rating">{data.data.attributes.rating}</div>
      <h2>{data.data.attributes.title}</h2>

      <small>console list</small>

      <p>{data.data.attributes.body}</p>

      <img
        width="500px"
        src={`http://localhost:1337` + image.data.url}
        alt="Not Working!"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Btw, sometimes it loads when I edit the code but when I refresh it, it doesn't load the image anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetch` API is asynchronous, so I'm assuming your `useFetch` hook sets the return value asynchronously. Therefore the image must be fetched on first load, and before the API has returned a response, the returned value will be empty. In other words, `image.data` will be null, resulting in the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'url')`. This also explains why the image loads after editing the code but not on first refresh.

To solve this error you can use optional chaining:

```
<img
  width="500px"
  src={`http://localhost:1337${image.data?.url}`}
  alt="Not Working!"
/>
```

The image still won't load properly until the data has been fetched from the API, but this will prevent any errors. If you have a placeholder URL you can use while the image data is still loading, you can use it like this:

```
<img
  width="500px"
  src={image.data?.url ? `http://localhost:1337${image.data?.url}` : placeholderURL}
  alt="Not Working!"
/>
```